# Code in link in spoiler is highlighted without hovering

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design, spoilers

In the example below, word `internets` is blue, even without hovering over the spoiler.

---

Code:

```
>! hello [world `internets`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)
```

---

Example:

> hello [world `internets`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Only happens if the link is followed though. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98358/when-editing-an-answer-with-spoilers-the-links-are-not-hidden-in-the-markdown-p Recommendation: don't put important information such as links into spoilers.

Comment: @Shog9 "Important"? Not sure what you mean by that. In any case, links in spoilers have a huge use-case here, namely explaining some obfuscation or technique with an external reference to supplement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue no longer seems reproduceable / has been fixed, so I am tagging this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Please let us know if this or a similar issue arises again.